# Aggressive behavior

Tags: dogs, behavior

When I come home from vacation, she squeals and barks aggressively and runs around. I can't ' tell if she if over excited or angry. She won't allow me to pick her up.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! It might help people answer your question if you provide us some more details about your dog such as Breed, Age and anything else that might be important here :)

Answer (score 2):

Dog?  Sounds like she is very happy to see you again, and maybe scolding you for being away so long.  Sounds just like a Bichon I used to own.

If you don't want to encourage it, turn your back on her.  Don't interact with her until she calms down.  *Do* reward her, by greeting her on your *own* terms, as soon as she brings it down to a level you can deal with.

> She won't allow me to pick her up

So don't.  Most small dogs don't enjoy being scooped up off the ground even if many of them will tolerate it.  I always tell mine what's coming, "I'm going to pick you up."  That way, it's not a total surprise.  Now he usually will climb into my arms on his own when I bend down and say that.

Comment: This is a good answer, why did you delete it?